# How to support this shelf?

Tags: wood, walls, shelf

I found this shelf already attached to supports and I'd like to put it up on the back of this cedar closet. The cedar closet is built out of a frame of 2"x4"s, but the width between the 2x4s doesn't line up with the shelf supports. See below:

[image: shelf on wall]

[image: shelf and wall]
(sorry the image is rotated, doesn't show as rotated on my end and keeps turning when uploaded)

I have more 2x4s and other scrap wood. Should I cut out and screw in two horizontal 2x4s on the inside gap in between the existing vertical 2x4s, to fill the gaps and screw the shelf into the new horizontal 2x4s? I may line up the shelf support on one of the existing 2x4s, then just fill in the gap for the other shelf support using one or two horizontal 2x4s to make a sturdy spot the shelf can screw into. Here's a sketch of what I'm talking about:

Is there a better way to go about this? Will my horizontal 2x4 additionals hold up the shelf sufficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Decide which wall studs (the vertical 2x4s) will support the shelf
2. Remove the brackets from the shelf
3. Attach the brackets to the selected studs
4. Place the shelf on top of the brackets
5. Fasten the shelf to the brackets